# Python seems to be skipping the bottom half of my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am trying to make a "guess the word" type game. Right now I have made two classes, each one for the computers random number (called `cpu_input` in the code). And a class for the user input, called `user_input` in the code.

```
class UserInput:
    def __init__(self, useri):
        self.useri = useri

    def get_char1(self):
        return self.useri[0]

    def get_char2(self):
        return self.useri[1]

    def get_char3(self):
        return self.useri[2]
```

The goal here is to have a three letter word generated, and have each character from the user input and the random word be accessible. For the purpose I need, this part is working fine.

The second class is identical to this one. Just for the randomly generated number.

```
class CpuInput:
    def __init__(self, cpui):
        self.cpui = cpui

    def get_char1(self):
        return self.cpui[0]

    def get_char2(self):
        return self.cpui[1]

    def get_char3(self):
        return self.cpui[2]
```

As before, this class is working perfectly fine, for its purpose in my program.

However, I run into a problem when I want to start comparing the user_input to the cpu_input.
This is what I have written:

```
cpu_input = CpuInput("Jet")
user_input = UserInput(input("Place user input here: "))

if cpu_input == user_input:
    print("Guessed correctly.")
```

Here I have set the `cpu_input` to ALWAYS be Jet for the sake of testing, whenever I enter Jet in the user input the program just comes to an end. Like, it just skips over the `if` completely?:
This is the output:

```
Place user input here: Jet

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong? Or a concept I'm just completely missing from my program? I really don't understand why the if statement isn't happening.

Comment: It's not skipping anything, the condition is not true. Add `else: ...` and you will see.

Comment: @matszwecja Thanks. Can you explain why it's not true?

Comment: @pythontommi see linked duplicate. Default behaviour for custom classes is comparing by `id`.

Comment: Why do you create 2 classes that are 100% identical

Answer (score 1):

You create two instances of (different) classes. They are *not* equal - you can verify this by printing `id(cpu_input) == id(user_input)`.

Even if both where instances of *the same class* - they are different object in memory with unique `id(..)`'s - hence not equal.

*A class is a concept of something - like "a tree" - choose any 2 trees (different or same species "aka class") - they are not equal - unless you pick the same tree twice.*

You store the values inside the classes - you can compare the class instance values you stored:

```
if cpu_input.cpui == user_input.cpui:  
    print("Guessed correctly.")
```

Adding a

```
else:
    print("Your comparison is not equal!")
```

will make it more clear when it is not the same.